# How long is an appoggiatura in triple time?

Tags: ornaments

I am currently playing in a baroque group.
The question has arisen as to how long an appoggiatura should be in triple or compound meters.

According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appoggiatura),

> The time subtracted is generally half the time value of the principal
>   note, though in simple triple or compound meters, for example, it
>   might receive two thirds of the time.

Is there a "rule" as to when it should receive one third of the time, and when two thirds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't play in Baroque ensembles, my experience with Baroque keyboard music tells me that the appoggiatura takes up two-thirds of the value.

A discussion on [Music Manuscript Notation in Bach](http://www.iment.com/maida/familytree/henry/music/bachnotation.htm#writtena) seems to corroborate this:

> The appoggiatura takes half the time of the following note, except when followed by a dotted note. It then usually takes two-thirds of the value of the note.

Thus the appoggiatura (the non-chord tone itself) takes two-thirds of the value, and the chord tone to which it resolves only occupies the final one-third of the value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! It seems intuitively strange to me, but maybe that's just because I'm taking the notation too literally, rather than thinking about the musical importance.

Comment: "Thus the appoggiatura (the non-chord tone itself) takes two-thirds of the value, and the chord tone to which it resolves only occupies the final one-third of the value." IMO this is too prescriptive. The actual length might be 2/3, 1/3, or even 1/6 or 1/12 of a long dotted note. It depends on the musical context, and what is happening in the rest of the harmony and/or counterpoint. In fact the appoggiatura can even take *all* of the written note, if that is followed by a rest which is replaced by the resolution of the ornament!

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly. Later in the link I gave it says "a certain freedom may be allowed in the applicaton of these rules, to preserve the improvisatory character of the appoggiatura."